# Dessen as demonstrativpronoun ? examples please

Tags: relative-pronoun, demonstrative-pronoun

Dessen can be Relativpronomens AND Demonstrativpronomens, can you please give examples of its role as demonstrativpronoun ?

witionary gives these examples for it:

[2] Die Matratze dessen, welches ich verkauft habe, war sehr hart.

[2] Ich erinnere mich dessen, was ich gestern tun wollte.

[2] Ich erinnere mich dessen, der mich gebissen hat.

Comment: The first example is weird, the other two at least stilted speech.

Answer (score 3):

An example from Kafka's *Das Schloß* ([source](https://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/das-schloss-9764/20)):

> *Daß sie die Fähigkeiten hatte, welche für diese Stelle nötig waren,* **das** wußte sie, **dessen** war sie ganz gewiß […]

*Das* und *dessen* both refer back to the initial clause; one is accusative object of *wissen*, the other genitive object of *gewiß (sein)*.

Note that *dessen* is often used cataphorically, i.e. it precedes the clause it refers to instead of following it. This is the case for the two relative clauses in the following example.

> Eher könnte man sagen, daß sie unter Aufopferung **dessen**, *was sie hatte*, und **dessen**, *was sie erwarten durfte*, uns beiden die Gelegenheit gegeben hat, uns auf höherem Posten zu bewähren

Answer (score 2):

The difference between a demonstrative and a relative pronoun (apart from the almost unused welcher/welche/welches) almost exclusively lies in the type of clause they are used in.

> Ich war bei Klaus, dessen Firma ihn gerade entlassen **hat**.

Main clause, relative clause. *Dessen* is used as a relative pronoun.

> Ich war bei Klaus, dessen Firma **hat** ihn gerade entlassen.

Main clause, main clause. *Dessen* is used as a demonstrative pronoun.

The difference between the two is very subtle. In the first sentence, the relative clause tags the information Klaus has got the pink slip as a property to Klaus. Maybe there's another Klaus we don't know of? In the second sentence, the concatenation of main clauses makes the statement more of a collection of independent facts. Klaus is known, the fact he got the pink slip is new.

German speakers pay most attention to the position of the finite verb when they listen, not so much to pronouns. But often enough, people use the main clause, main clause variant because they began to speak before they had all the facts arranged, so it may be just sloppyness.